# How to Enable option HTTPs redirect in blogspot

Tags: https, blogger, blogspot

I have set my custom domain :

Before set my custom domain HTTPS redirect Option is Enable but
After set my custom domain HTTPS redirect Option is Disable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6284029?visit_id=1-636436864045942322-81118403&p=blog_security_https&rd=1) is currently not available for custom domain blogs.

Comment: But available with CloudFlare: https://blog.cloudflare.com/ssl-on-tumblr-wordpress-blogger-appengine-pos/

Comment: But My question is How to enable **https redirect** option.

Note : I m using blospot

Comment: It's available now from draft.blogger.com, check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can now [enable blogger free SSL in custom domain](https://blogger.goyllo.com/2018/01/use-https-in-blogger-custom-domain.html) as well. To do that

1. First go to [draft.blogger.com](https://draft.blogger.com) (this is the place where you can see latest updates from blogger)
2. Now go to setting > basic and enable https availability.
   [image]
3. Now go back to your main blogger dashboard (blogger.com).
4. Wait for few minutes, because blogger automatically register your SSL certifiate, when they done it, you will see same option there to enable it.